# Extra space in the end of string

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, xcode4.2

I'm going through my array and find at which index the searched word is at. I use that information to put space between the words until i reach the next word. I save that text, and then store it in a variable.

I'm suspecting that my comparison between the lastObject and the arr objectAtIndex: i is not working, but i can't seem to figure out why?

NSArray *arr;

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:_exerciseDocument];

while(![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    NSString *buffer;
    if([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] intoString:&buffer])
        {
          [scanner scanUpToString:" " intoString:&buffer];          
          [scanner scanString:@" " intoString:nil];  
        }
    else
        {

        }

for(int i=0; i <arr.count; i++)
{
    NSString *stringToCheck = (NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:i];
    if([stringToCheck isEqualToString:@"Fokus:"])
    {
        _descriptionIndex = i;
    }
    if([stringToCheck isEqualToString:@"Niveau:"])
    {
        _focusIndex = i;
    }
    if([stringToCheck isEqualToString:@"Redskab:"])
    {
        _niveauIndex = i;
    }
    if([stringToCheck isEqualToString:@"Vanddybde:"])
    {
        _equipmentIndex = i;
    }
}

_descriptiontToTextField = [[NSString alloc]init];
for(int i=1; i <_descriptionIndex; i++)
{
    if(![[arr lastObject] isEqual:[arr objectAtIndex:i]])
    {
        _descriptiontToTextField = [_descriptiontToTextField stringByAppendingString:[ arr objectAtIndex:i]];
        _descriptiontToTextField = [_descriptiontToTextField stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    }
    else
    {
        _descriptiontToTextField = [_descriptiontToTextField stringByAppendingString:[ arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the expected input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]` doesn't work the way you may think it does. If there are multiple spaces between words in `_exerciseDocument`, you're going to end up with a lot of empty strings in `arr`, which is not what you want. You may want to consider the use of a `NSScanner` (which, by default, skips whitespace and newline characters) to create your array.

Second, arr contains strings, and no other kind of objects. Given this, you should be using `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` instead for your comparisons.

Third, is there a reason you're starting your second loop at index 1 instead of index 0?

Comment: I know that the text document i'm reading from will not contain more than one space between each word, so that should not be a problem, but i'm curious how you would implement this with NSScanner? I'm starting at index 1, because i don't want the first word in the file into the string.

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk : You'd set up your scanner with your _exerciseDocument string, stripping off the leading and trailing spaces first. You'd implement a while loop with (![scanner isAtEnd]) as the condition. Inside the loop, you'd first use the scanner to scan up to characters in +[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet], getting the string by reference. Then you'd scan the whitespace and newline characters, passing NULL for the string reference, because you won't care about those characters. As you read in your strings, you add them to a mutable array.

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk : The only advantage this offers is the ability to deal with multiple spaces between words (which, as you pointed out, isn't an issue). But when you can't rely on there being only one space, it works really well.

Comment: I'm thinking you mean something like this (i've updated my original code snippet), but i'm not sure what should go inside the if-else statement?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk : Actually, no; I was providing all of that as an alternative method of filling your arr array. But when it comes to the scanner, don't forget that you have to scan *up to* the characters in the character set, to grab your string, then scan the characters in the character set to skip over them.

Comment: I've updated my code again, but i'm what about the data that comes after the " "? I'm trying to implement this just, so that i'm sure there won't be any more extra spaces. Also i don't understand when I'm suppose to put the string in the array? Am i already doing the trimming of spaces in the beginning and end? I'm sorry for the newbie questions, i have never used nsscanner before, and i'm still relative new to objective-c.

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk : Eliminate the `-scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:` call; you've got one too many in there. (Maybe you can use the characters variants later.) Once you get your string in `buffer`, you can then pass it to addObject: on your `NSMutableArray` `arr` to add it to the array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9619/discussion-between-niels-sonderbaek-and-trudyscousin)

Answer (score 1):

That if-statement never results to YES because your for-loop always terminates before reaching the last object in your array: i < _descriptionIndex.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to compare last object in array with all the objects inthe array, but isEqual is used to compare for two objects type not the values in the objects , as you can see

> NSArray *arr = [_exerciseDocument componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

this will create arr as array of strings means all the objects are of type [NSString class]

> if(![[arr lastObject] isEqual:[arr objectAtIndex:i]])

since all the objects are of same type isEqual will return true so your code will run in else part because of negation in if condition so use isEqualToString for comparing strings